# how to separate Mobile and Web design in Angular Ionic project?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an application that would be mobile and web-based. The idea is to generate an app for android, ios + web with just one code.

It is an application where users can register and
Manage products. This would happen via a mobile and web application. I want to use same logic with different designs for mobile and desktop.

what i am using right now is **Platform** from angular to detect which device it is.  I don't know if it is best Practice or not and i have so much duplicate code because of this.

can anyone suggest better way to approach this ?
Also don’t want to have code Duplication.

Appreciate the help Thank you

Comment: If we are talking design as in (S)CSS you could manage layout with [Ion-Grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid) paired together with media queries. And as you said you will need to handle plugins that isnt supported with browser using the platform to check.

Comment: no i mean html part

Comment: Okey so you need to render entirely different html depending on the device? Then it sounds like using platform is the way to go. To reduce duplicate code you could create a service that has an behaviourSubject which hold the value of what kind of platform is used, that way you just need to check the behavioursubject when you need to

Comment: That is exactly what i am Doing right now . Thank you :)